# RadGrid Export To Excel Layout Issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, export-to-excel, radgrid

So I have a Grid with a MasterTableView that contains a DetailTable, and that DetailTable contains a DetailTable.  Everything is correct as far as layout indentation when it renders to the screen and when I export to pdf. But the problem is when I try to export to excel. When the spreadsheet opens the MasterTableView item is say 7 columns wide. The first DetailTable item is say 5 columns wide, and the second DetailTable items are 3 columns wide. And they appear like they are center aligned so it looks like an upside down pyramid.  My client does not like this and I have tried for hours now to figure out how to make the item indentations look like they do in the pdf and screen but with no luck.  Is there a setting or something to make the excel render correctly or is this a bug.  Below will be my grid markup, and I'll attach an image of the spreadsheet so you can see what it looks like.  Thanks for any help in this issue.

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" ShowFooter="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="false" CellSpacing="5" AllowFilteringByColumn="false">
    <ExportSettings HideStructureColumns="true" ExportOnlyData="true" IgnorePaging="true" OpenInNewWindow="true">
        <Pdf AllowAdd="false" AllowCopy="true" AllowModify="false" AllowPrinting="true" PageTitle="ESign Sent vs Sold"
            Title="ESign Sent vs Sold" PaperSize="A4" PageWidth="260mm" />
        <Excel Format="Html" />
    </ExportSettings>

    <ClientSettings AllowExpandCollapse="true">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    </ClientSettings>

    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ParentID, ID" Name="DivisionTable" HierarchyLoadMode="Client" HierarchyDefaultExpanded="false" ClientDataKeyNames="ParentID, ID">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" />
        <ItemStyle Wrap="false" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle Wrap="false" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <FooterStyle Wrap="false" />

        <DetailTables>
        <telerik:GridTableView Name="RegionTable" DataKeyNames="ParentID, ID" ClientDataKeyNames="ParentID, ID" HierarchyLoadMode="Client" Width="100%" HierarchyDefaultExpanded="false" >
            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView Name="BranchTable" DataKeyNames="ParentID, ID" ClientDataKeyNames="ParentID, ID" HierarchyLoadMode="Client" Width="100%" HierarchyDefaultExpanded="false" >
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Filler" ItemStyle-Width="25px" HeaderStyle-Width="25px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Text" DataField="Text" SortExpression="Text" HeaderText="Branch" ItemStyle-Width="300px" HeaderStyle-Width="300px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SentCount" DataField="SentCount" SortExpression="SentCount" HeaderText="ESign Sent" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SoldCount" DataField="SoldCount" SortExpression="SoldCount" HeaderText="Sold w/ ESign"  />
                    </Columns>
                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Text" DataField="Text" SortExpression="Text" HeaderText="Region" ItemStyle-Width="300px" HeaderStyle-Width="300px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SentCount" DataField="SentCount" SortExpression="SentCount" HeaderText="ESign Sent" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SoldCount" DataField="SoldCount" SortExpression="SoldCount" HeaderText="Sold w/ ESign"  />
            </Columns>
        </telerik:GridTableView>
        </DetailTables>

        <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Text" DataField="Text" SortExpression="Text" HeaderText="Division" ItemStyle-Width="300px" HeaderStyle-Width="300px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SentCount" DataField="SentCount" SortExpression="SentCount" HeaderText="ESign Sent" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Width="150px"   />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SoldCount" DataField="SoldCount" SortExpression="SoldCount" HeaderText="Sold w/ ESign"  />
        </Columns>

    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, the built in Excel export functionality is unreliable.

Add an export button to your page, and try using this instead:

```
   protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";

        this.EnableViewState = false;
        System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
        RadGrid1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Taking another look at your example, I see that you're using detail tables too. I'm not sure if this solution will work with detail tables, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah, I tried what you had. Unfortunately it threw an exception. Said something about the RadGrid needed to be registered with the script manager. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: so... does that mean this isn't the answer?

Comment: I'm trying the samething with my RadGrid but I receive this error message **RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();**

Comment: Are you calling `RegisterForEventValidation()` at some point in your code, or is the error being returned from the control? One option, although not entirely secure, might be to disable event validation on the page. Otherwise, if you can clarify where the error is coming from by posting the stack trace, I will try to help out a bit more.